# Excel 2010: Use IF with FIND. Results in both -1 & -10 (only -1 required)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

**Program:** Excel 2010
**Experience:** Basic

Hi there,
I've managed to master (to my experience level) the `FIND/SEARCH` cells for text and respond accordingly, however in the case of `-1` & `-10` I get which ever is in the cell (see below).

I am creating a secondary table to use as a base for a Dependent Dropdown.  If I choose in my 1st dropdown ManID #3 then my second will only show:  `1401-3, 1402-3`  etc.

1 = `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-1",$A25)),($A25), "y")`
2 = `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-2",$A25)),($A25), "y")`  and so on
(the "y" will be removed once I know the code is working.

As you can see below the `1` returns the `1306-10` value, when it should be a `"y"`.

```
| ReportManIDUnq | 1       | 2      | 3      | 4      | c1      | z      |
|----------------|---------|--------|--------|--------|---------|--------|
| 1401-3         | y       | y      | 1401-3 | y      | y       | y      |
| 1312-4         | y       | y      | y      | 1312-4 | y       | y      |
| 1311-5         | y       | y      | y      | y      | y       | y      |
| 1310-6         | y       | y      | y      | y      | y       | y      |
| 1309-7         | y       | y      | y      | y      | y       | y      |
| 1308-8         | y       | y      | y      | y      | y       | y      |
| 1307-9         | y       | y      | y      | y      | y       | y      |
| 1306-10        | 1306-10 | y      | y      | y      | y       | y      |
| 1402-1         | 1402-1  | y      | y      | y      | y       | y      |
| 1402-2         | y       | 1402-2 | y      | y      | y       | y      |
| 1402-3         | y       | y      | 1402-3 | y      | y       | y      |
| 1402-4         | y       | y      | y      | 1402-4 | y       | y      |
| 1402-5         | y       | y      | y      | y      | y       | y      |
| 1402-c1        | y       | y      | y      | y      | 1402-c1 | y      |
| 1402-z         | y       | y      | y      | y      | y       | 1402-z |
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are no leading/trailing spaces around your cell entries/contents, I would use the following formula

```
=IF(RIGHT($A2,LEN(B$1)+1)="-"&B$1,$A2,"y")
```

in cell B2 and then drag that over the entire range.

[image]

The above checks whether the entry in column A corresponding to the row you're in has a `-` followed by the column header *exactly*. More specifically, `RIGHT($A2,LEN(B$1)+1)` extracts the right `LEN(B$1)+1` (length of the contents of `B$1` plus one) characters from `$A2`; this is then compared against `"-"&B$1` which is the column header preceded by a concatenated `-`.

Comment: thank you :)  Perfectly, and thank you for the explanation, I can take a lot from that.  Happy camper!